# TFS Merge issue - source changed when merging source into target

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge

Im using vs2012 and TFS

I have a solution in tfs that I will for example call target
I create a file called AccountController:

```
public class AccountController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      string test = "Rick";

      return View(test);
   }
}
```

I check in the file.

I create a branch from target called source
In source, I made changes to AccountController:

```
public class AccountController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      string test = "Rick";

      // new stuff
      test=test+"!";

      return View(test);
   }
}
```

I check in the code to source
I merge source into target.
I look at target and the two new lines are there
I look at source and the two new lines are missing!!

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: What type of merge did you perform? If you check the "Track Changeset" on changeset, does TFS think it has merged it? Also, are you talking about the change missing in the checked in code, or in pending changes after the merge?

Comment: view your history on each file, I bet you didn't do what you think you did...